# Biggest rise in a time window in a time series

Tags: python, pandas

Wondering if there is a fast way of getting the biggest rise in a time series within a window.

Intended code is...

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

base = datetime.datetime.today()

date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 365)]

data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=len(date_list))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list, 'value': data})

def biggest_rise(df, windowsize = 10):
    '''gets the biggest rise within a window size specified
    '''
    # Some magic code here
    return df.rolling_max(window=10, ...)
```

Comment: What is your definition of 'rise'?

Comment: Rise means when the 10th (windowsize) data point is higher than the first data point.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer... as per code below. Upped the high to 10K to really see the changes:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

base = datetime.datetime.today()

date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 365)]

data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10000, size=len(date_list))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list, 'value': data})

window = 10

dfs = [df.iloc[i: i+window] for i in range(0, len(df)) if i+window < len(df)]

biggest_rise = max([d.value.max()-d.value.min() for d in dfs])
```

- Takes `112 ms` for 365 datapoints. Anything better is welcome.
- The biggest_rise could be the biggest_fall in the window. Don't know how to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean 'biggest rise', but using rolling may be helpful. For example with that code you can get the difference of the maximum and minimum value within a 10-day window:

```
df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').rolling('10d').max() - df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').rolling('10d').min()
```

Comment: Nice. This code takes just `11 ms` on a second run. Rise is when the 10th data-point is greater than the first data-point for a 10-day window. How can one weed out the falls?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better answer to get the maximum rise using @TywinLannister88 suggestion:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

base = datetime.datetime.today()

date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 365)]

data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10000, size=len(date_list))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list, 'value': data})

# 10-day rolling window
df1 = df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').rolling('10d').max() - \
      df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').rolling('10d').min()

# percent change to see if there is a rise or fall
df2 = df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').value.pct_change(periods=10)

# filter out the rises (pctchange > 0) and find the maximum rise
df3 = df.sort_values(['date']).set_index('date').assign(delta=df1, pctchange=df2)
biggest_rise = df3[df3.pctchange>0].pctchange.max()
```